# TypeScript: assert an object literal has key-values that equal each other

Tags: typescript

Is it possible in TypeScript to assert that a `const` object literal is made in such a way where each key equals its value?

In other words:

```js
// Good
const testIds: KeyEqualsValue = {
  foo: 'foo'
} as const

// Bad
const testIds: KeyEqualsValue = {
  foo: 'bar' // Error
} as const
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not with a single type, you can do it with a function:

```
function propAsValue<T extends { [P in keyof T]: P }>(o: T) {
    return o;
}
const testIds = propAsValue({
    foo: 'foo'
});

const testIds2 = propAsValue({
    foo: 'bar'
});
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=10&ssc=4&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABABwE52QQQM4DUCGANiAKYA8AKoiQB5QlgAm2iA3ogNoAKiMSA1iQCecYIgoBdAFyIeAXwB8ACjgyKASjYAoRLsSoSUEKiRwA3FrlaICbFET07ASWaIAvCnRY8RUktY6esBwqogA5MFwYZbqFta29o5QLtgATO6eGDgExCT+gbqRMmEARvio0XKxWkA)

Or with an inline function, if you want to be terse and confuse everyone:

```
const testIds = (<T extends { [P in keyof T]: P }>(o: T) => o)({
    foo: 'foo'
});
```

Although I am not sure what your use case for this is, you might be better off with using `Object.keys`.

Comment: Very cool. This worked for me. Thanks! I use these test IDs for different elements on the page so I want them to be unique, and I also want to be able to type other functions parameters as being `keyof typeof testIds`. Your solution meets these requirements :)

Comment: `T extends [...] keyof T` My mind cannot wrap around how this is not a cyclical derivation.

Comment: Does this function ever get run during runtime? Or is it even compiled into the build?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can get the object keys with [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) then you can loop through the keys and compare the string values. If they do not equal you can throw an error.

Comment: Thank you but I wanted a compile-time check, not run-time.